# Shorten java source code

Tags: java, mongodb

The following code intends to create a search column in my project. But I highly doubt the efficiency of the code since it is quite lengthy. Is there a possible way to perform the task relating to the code with reduced number of lines of code?

```
package kelas_java;
public class searchingDariSemuaKolom {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicDBObject sortOrder = new BasicDBObject();
    MongoClient mongoClient;
    DB db;

    DBCollection table, table2;
    DBCursor cur = null, cur2 = null;
    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        db = mongoClient.getDB("face");
        boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku", "kamu".toCharArray());
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("1");
//start1
table = db.getCollection("titles");
        DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("link", regex);
        DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("title", regex);
        DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("body", regex);
        DBObject clause4 = new BasicDBObject("date", regex);
        BasicDBList or1 = new BasicDBList();
        or1.add(clause1);
        or1.add(clause2);
        or1.add(clause3);
        or1.add(clause4);
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or1);
        cur = table.find(query);
        while (cur.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cur.next().get("title"));
        }
//end1
//start2
table2 = db.getCollection("news");
        DBObject clause5 = new BasicDBObject("link", regex);
        DBObject clause6 = new BasicDBObject("title", regex);
        DBObject clause7 = new BasicDBObject("body", regex);
        DBObject clause8 = new BasicDBObject("date", regex);
        BasicDBList or2 = new BasicDBList();
        or2.add(clause1);
        or2.add(clause2);
        or2.add(clause3);
        or2.add(clause4);
        DBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("$or", or2);
        cur2 = table2.find(query2);
        while (cur2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cur2.next().get("title"));
        }
//end2
 } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        cur.close();
        cur2.close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always use methods to shorten the code. and when you need to do same work several times, just call your method and pass true arguments to it.

here is some changes on your code, i removed your Repetitious code which was printing some data from data base, and i created a method called `doPrint` which takes four arguments.

- string array named keys, which it's values will be assigned to `BasicDBObject`'s.
- a value that will be assigned to `BasicDBObject`'s.
- the db that you are connected with it.
- and the collection (table) name that you want to read data from it.

then all you need to printing is to call `doPrint`

```
doPrint(keys , regex , db , "titles");
```

hope it helps.

```
package kelas_java;
public class searchingDariSemuaKolom {

    static void doPrint(String keys, Object value, DB db, String collectionName) {
        BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
        for (String key : keys) {
            or.add(new BasicDBObject(key, value));
        }
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection(collectionName);

        try {
            DBCursor cur = table.find(query);
            while (cur.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cur.next().get("title"));
            }
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            cur.close();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicDBObject sortOrder = new BasicDBObject();
        MongoClient mongoClient;
        DB db;

        String strs[] = {
            "link", 
            "title",
            "body", 
            "date", 
        };
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            db = mongoClient.getDB("face");
            boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku", "kamu".toCharArray());
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("1");

            //start1
            doPrint(keys , regex , db , "titles");
            //start2
            doPrint(keys , regex , db , "news");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, it succes, you helped me alot...
i understanding about using method, but i never try to make shorten code than before :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Rahmat beat me to it, but figured I might as well post.

Your problem is more lengthiness than efficiency.

Only put things in a try/catch if there's an unpredictable reason that it might fail. And then only put that line that might fail in, not all of your code. Then, in the 'catch', specify the expected error, and what you want to do about it.

Reading the file, analyzing the information inside, etc, would go after the catch.

Personally, I prefer not to create additional variable when they're not being used more than once or helpful for clarity. But that's up to you.

Also, you never used sortOrder. And class names should be capitalized, no big deal though.

```
package kelas_java;
public class SearchingDariSemuaKolom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Not sure which of these need to be in here
       try {
           MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
           DB db = mongoClient.getDB("face");
           boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku", "kamu".toCharArray());
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
       }

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("1");

        String[] stuffToAdd = {"link", "title", "body", "date"};

        BasicDBList or1 = method2(db, "titles", stuffToAdd);
        BasicDBList or2 = method2(db, "news", stuffToAdd);
    }

    public BasicDbList method2(DB db, String str, String[] stuffToAdd) {
       BasicDBList or = createDbList(stuffToAdd);
       DBCollection table = db.getCollection(str);
       DBCursor cur = table.find(new BasicDBObject("$or", or));
       while (cur.hasNext())
           System.out.println(cur.next().get(str));
       cur.close();
       return or;
    }

    public BasicDbList createDbList(String[] toAdd) {
        BasicDbList or = new BasicDbList();
        for(String newString : toAdd)
            or.add(new BasicDbObject(newString, regex));
        return or;
    }

}
```

Comment: hehe i forget to remove sortOrder, i erase that feature bfore, thanks for your help..i'll read and try your source too mate, i will compare you guys source, also my source too...thanks a lot..it will become my reference :)

Comment: btw why u suggest me that classname be better if first letter using capitalized?

Comment: Coding conventions. Your code will work fine regardless of capitalization. But when you see something capitalized, you can automatically think class, and when it's lowercase, you think object/method. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html.